# Changing PC's timezone according to current timezone value using a BATCH FILE

Tags: batch-file, timezone

So I'm trying to create a batch file to change the pc's timezone according to the current timezone on it (Working on Win 8.1 btw). 
here's what I have so far:

```
set current="timezone value"
if %current%=="S.A. Pacific Standard Time" TZUTIL s/"China Standard Time" else TZUTIL s/"S.A. Pacific Standard Time"
```

How do I get the current timezone value of my pc so I can set %current% right?
Is there another way to do it without using TZUTIL?, how do you recommend me do it?

Comment: Two things: 1) There is no zone `"S.A. Pacific Standard Time"`.  It's `"SA Pacific Standard Time"`.  Remove the periods.   2) The logic here doesn't make sense to me.  Why you would to this?  Running this multiple times will toggle between two different zones.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: 1) You´re right, unfortunately I found out after I got the answer from @Paul. 2)Yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('TZUTIL /g') do set "current=%%a"
echo %current%
```

Also your command has incorrect switch and missing quotes in comparison

```
if "%current%"=="S.A. Pacific Standard Time" (
  TZUTIL /s "China Standard Time"
) else (
  TZUTIL /s "S.A. Pacific Standard Time"
)
```